# WP - Get stylesheet_directory in JS

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to get stylesheet_directory in JS, but can't get it to work.

Here is what I have tried:

```
url : '<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/hamburger.svg'
```

AND:

```
var stylesheetDir = "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>"; 
url : '$stylesheetDir/img/hamburger.svg',
```

I guess there is just a problem with some characters or something? Could you please help me out?

**svgicons-config-js**

```
var stylesheetDir = "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>"; 
url == $stylesheetDir;
decodeURI(url);


var svgIconConfig = {
    hamburgerCross : {
        url : stylesheetDir + '/img/hamburger.svg',
        animation : [
            { 
                el : 'path:nth-child(1)', 
                animProperties : { 
                    from : { val : '{"path" : "m 5.0916789,20.818994 53.8166421,0"}' }, 
                    to : { val : '{"path" : "M 12.972944,50.936147 51.027056,12.882035"}' }
                } 
            },
            { 
                el : 'path:nth-child(2)', 
                animProperties : { 
                    from : { val : '{"transform" : "s1 1", "opacity" : 1}', before : '{"transform" : "s0 0"}' }, 
                    to : { val : '{"opacity" : 0}' }
                } 
            },
            { 
                el : 'path:nth-child(3)', 
                animProperties : { 
                    from : { val : '{"path" : "m 5.0916788,42.95698 53.8166422,0"}' }, 
                    to : { val : '{"path" : "M 12.972944,12.882035 51.027056,50.936147"}' }
                } 
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

**hamburger_animation.js**

```
   (function() {                            
        [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.si-icons-default > .si-icon' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {
            var svgicon = new svgIcon( el, svgIconConfig );
        } );
        new svgIcon( document.querySelector( '.si-icons-easing .si-icon-hamburger' ), svgIconConfig, { easing : mina.backin } );
        new svgIcon( document.querySelector( '.si-icons-easing .si-icon-hamburger-cross' ), svgIconConfig, { easing : mina.elastic, speed: 600              } );
        })();
```

**svgicons.js**

```
/**
 * svgicons.js v1.0.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * Copyright 2013, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
;( function( window ) {

    'use strict';

    /*** helper functions ***/

    // from https://github.com/desandro/classie/blob/master/classie.js
    function classReg( className ) {
        return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
    }

    function hasClass( el, c ) {
        return 'classList' in document.documentElement ? el.classList.contains( c ) : classReg( c ).test( el.className )
    }

    function extend( a, b ) {
        for( var key in b ) { 
            if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    // from http://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/989439
    function mobilecheck() {
        var check = false;
        (function(a){if(/(android|ipad|playbook|silk|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
        return check;
    }

    // http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=5259
    function isMouseLeaveOrEnter( e, handler ) { 
        if (e.type != 'mouseout' && e.type != 'mouseover') return false; 
        var reltg = e.relatedTarget ? e.relatedTarget : 
        e.type == 'mouseout' ? e.toElement : e.fromElement; 
        while (reltg && reltg != handler) reltg = reltg.parentNode; 
        return (reltg != handler); 
    }

    /*** svgIcon ***/

    function svgIcon( el, config, options ) {
        this.el = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this.svg = Snap( this.options.size.w, this.options.size.h );
        this.svg.attr( 'viewBox', '0 0 64 64' );
        this.el.appendChild( this.svg.node );
        // state
        this.toggled = false;
        // click event (if mobile use touchstart)
        this.clickevent = mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
        // icons configuration
        this.config = config[ this.el.getAttribute( 'data-icon-name' ) ];
        // reverse?
        if( hasClass( this.el, 'si-icon-reverse' ) ) {
            this.reverse = true;
        }
        if( !this.config ) return;
        var self = this;
        // load external svg
        Snap.load( this.config.url, function (f) {
            var g = f.select( 'g' );
            self.svg.append( g );
            self.options.onLoad();
            self._initEvents();
            if( self.reverse ) {
                self.toggle();
            }
        });
    }

    svgIcon.prototype.options = {
        speed : 200,
        easing : mina.linear,
        evtoggle : 'click', // click || mouseover
        size : { w : 64, h : 64 },
        onLoad : function() { return false; },
        onToggle : function() { return false; }
    };

    svgIcon.prototype._initEvents = function() {
        var self = this, toggleFn =  function( ev ) {
                if( ( ( ev.type.toLowerCase() === 'mouseover' || ev.type.toLowerCase() === 'mouseout' ) && isMouseLeaveOrEnter( ev, this ) ) || ev.type.toLowerCase() === self.clickevent ) {
                    self.toggle(true);
                    self.options.onToggle();    
                }
            };

        if( this.options.evtoggle === 'mouseover' ) {
            this.el.addEventListener( 'mouseover', toggleFn );
            this.el.addEventListener( 'mouseout', toggleFn );
        }
        else {
            this.el.addEventListener( this.clickevent, toggleFn );
        }
    };

    svgIcon.prototype.toggle = function( motion ) {
        if( !this.config.animation ) return;
        var self = this;
        for( var i = 0, len = this.config.animation.length; i < len; ++i ) {
            var a = this.config.animation[ i ],
                el = this.svg.select( a.el ),
                animProp = this.toggled ? a.animProperties.from : a.animProperties.to,
                val = animProp.val, 
                timeout = motion && animProp.delayFactor ? animProp.delayFactor : 0;

            if( animProp.before ) {
                el.attr( JSON.parse( animProp.before ) );
            }

            if( motion ) {
                setTimeout(function( el, val, animProp ) { 
                    return function() { el.animate( JSON.parse( val ), self.options.speed, self.options.easing, function() {
                        if( animProp.after ) {
                            this.attr( JSON.parse( animProp.after ) );
                        }
                        if( animProp.animAfter ) {
                            this.animate( JSON.parse( animProp.animAfter ), self.options.speed, self.options.easing );
                        }
                    } ); }; 
                }( el, val, animProp ), timeout * self.options.speed );
            }
            else {
                el.attr( JSON.parse( val ) );
            }

        }
        this.toggled = !this.toggled;
    };

    // add to global namespace
    window.svgIcon = svgIcon;

})( window );
```

The site can be found here: http://goo.gl/wuUwUG

Please inspect element (or similar), and look at the code where it says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

`url : '$stylesheetDir/img/hamburger.svg',`

use

`url : stylesheetDir + '/img/hamburger.svg',`

**EDIT**

So, the following code is obsolete and unnecessary (it does nothing and can be removed):

`url == $stylesheetDir;
decodeURI(url);`

Feel free to remove it. Other than that everything looks fine.

I guess some more code is needed. You should reveal how you're using the `svgIconConfig` variable, and specifically, the `url` property.

**EDIT**

Thanks for revealing some more code. It appears that you're calling a `<?php ... ?>` block within a JS file. This block is not parsed by the server, so it is directly displayed instead of rendering the URL to the theme.

I'm not sure how you're enqueueing the scripts in the code, so I'll propose a solution that will work with any use case.

To fix this, insert the following in your theme functions.php

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_js_var_stylesheet_directory', 9);
function my_js_var_stylesheet_directory() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'var stylesheetDir = "' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '"';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

and delete the top 3 lines from your svgicons-config-js file, as they are unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you. That seems right. However, I got the following error:
https://[URL]/%3C?php%20bloginfo(%27stylesheet_directory%27)%20?%3E/img/hamburger.svg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Any ideas? [URL] means the url for the site

Comment: You're encoding the URL when using it for loading your svg, so you should decode it first before using it. To decode it, use `decodeURI(uri)`.

Comment: Thank you. Of course. My apologies, but I don't feel so familiar with js. I get the error "uri is not defined"

Comment: Your property name is `url` and not `uri`, so you should use `decodeURI(url)` - note the `url` instead of `uri` inside the function.

Comment: Thank you for holding out with me. I have tried to replace `uri` with both `url`, `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>`, `stylesheetDir` and so forth, but nothing works.

Comment: Please, provide some more code. Without context and display of the usage of the above code, I'm unable to help you further.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I will add some more code right now.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my post. I will also post a link to the page. I believe the problem is the decoding, as you mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks. Please, see my last edit - I've explained everything there. This should solve the issue for you. It's not the decoding at all. :)

Comment: Thank you. I've done the steps, but I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: stylesheetDir is not defined".

Comment: I've updated my comment. Please, update the `my_js_var_stylesheet_directory()` function with the latest one from my comment.

Comment: Congratulation. You just solved the problem. Thank you very much for helping me out! It really made my day. Have a nice day :)

Comment: It was much easier to understand your issue when I was able to see the whole picture. Have fun! :)

Answer (score 1):

From your code you have to echo the path for the css directory.

Check this one out :

```
var stylesheetDir = '<?php echo loginfo('stylesheet_directory') ; ?>/img/hamburger.svg';
console.log(stylesheetDir);
```

Comment: Remember to put that code on a php file so it gets parsed, it won't work on a javascript file